# In a jQuery click event, call a function stored in separate dojo js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dojo, esri

When trying to break up the JS code, I've pulled my jQuery bootstrap click events into their own file.

Everything loads correctly but when trying to reference a function that is in my dojo file from the jQuery file, the end result is "zoomToStreams not defined()";

Is there a proper way to break everything out into easily managed pieces for code-reusability and have the different libraries (jQuery, dojo) co-exist?  Both are loaded via  tags at the foot of my document.

```
// dojo.js

require(["dojo modules",...],function(dojo,...) {
    ...
    function zoomToStream(targetStream) {
       ...
    }
});

// jQuery.js

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#streamSelection li").click(function(e) {
        switch (e.target.text) {
            case "All Streams":
                zoomToStream("all");
                break;
            case "First Stream";
                zoomToStream("1");
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Could you create a define() that returns that function or an object that contains that function? at that point you could pull it in using require() the same way you are dojo.

Comment: `"zoomToStreams not defined()"` - The function you are using is `zoomToStream` NOT `zoomToStreams`

Comment: @KevinB, Would that fix the issue though as it's within the jQuery code that can't see the function that lives in the Dojo code?  And if so, I assume I specify it within the DojoConfig code block to define it.

Comment: @Dom, Thanks, that's just a typo in me writing up my write-up.  I didn't copy/paste from the console for that and was recalling from memory.  It is referenced correctly in the jQuery code and works when called from 1 JS file instead of two separate ones.

Comment: my point was to create a module that would return that function as an export, then require that module for your jquery code. your jquery wouldn't need to care whether or not the function uses dojo, it just needs access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your first snippet into a module that you can then require for your jquery code.

dojo.js (this isn't really what you named your js file is it?)

```
define("zoomToStream",["dojo modules",...], function(dojo,...) {
    ...
    function zoomToStream(targetStream) {
       ...
    }
    return zoomToStream;
});
```

jQuery.js (this isn't really what you named your js file is it?)

```
require(["zoomToStream"],function(zoomToStream) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#streamSelection li").click(function(e) {
            switch (e.target.text) {
                case "All Streams":
                    zoomToStream("all");
                    break;
                case "First Stream";
                    zoomToStream("1");
                    break;
                ...
            }
        }
    });
});
```

modify to fit your file structure etc, kinda seems odd to use those filenames for your js files.

Comment: Thx. Didn't think of it this way. And no, not names those.